# pandas: a date object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to read a bunch of dates represented as strings  into a data frame using the following:

```
import pandas as pd

TIMESTAMP_KEY = 'Date'
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
DATE_PARSER = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, TIMESTAMP_FORMAT)

pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=[TIMESTAMP_KEY], date_parser=DATE_PARSER)
```

where `file.csv` contains a column called `Date` with date strings formatted as `%Y-%m-%d`, i.e. `2014-11-01`.

This produces a pandas `TimeStamp` object, which prints

```
2015-11-01 00:00:00
```

However, **I don't want the time element**. Is there a neat solution to this, please?

Is the only approach to do (given that the index points to the `Date` column):

```
df.index = [index.date() for index in df.index]
```

... or can you specify this on the `DATE_PARSER`?

Comment: But why don't you want the `time` element, it's part of the `datetime64`, which is useful. If nothing has a time part it wont be written to a csv or displayed despite it being in the underlying values.

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for the interest. End game is to create a `Numpy.arange` and having the time element messes that up.

Comment: @ALollz And also, if I'm specifying a `date_parser` that clearly has no time element, why would pandas arbitrarily chose one for me?

Comment: Because you need a time part to accurately do math between dates. All dates can be converted to a number (i.e. number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00). Without a time part you're imprecise to 86,400 seconds, so how would math proceed? `pandas` makes a consistent decision to set all the time parts to '00:00:00` which allows for arithmetic and operations to occur consistently across all dates.